# Eclipse Indigo, no plugins will install, I dont know what to do?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins

I have Eclipse Java EE, and am trying to install Eclipse plugins to know avail.

I tried installing, hibernate tools, findbugs, egit, subeclipse and other plugins but none install. I have tried literally everything, I have searched the internet for help and did not find much. I have unchecked the update sites in preferences, re installed eclipse many times, opened it up as administrator and I still get the same errors. Here are some of the errors I have gotten if anyone knows how to fix this please let me know.

Here are the errors I got, please help!!

```
 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/com.collabnet.subversion.merge_2.2.4.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl_1.6.17.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar.
Connection reset
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/com.collabnet.subversion.merge_2.2.4.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/com.sun.jna_3.2.7.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl_1.6.17.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tmatesoft.svnkit_1.3.5.7406.jar.
Connection reset
```

Comment: you are probably behind a proxy server that is blocking access

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.subclipse.user/15976/match=) worked for me.

As noted in the bug reports, it affects all plugins, not just Subclipse, and the workaround is to make the eclipse install dir owned/writable by the user who is running eclipse.

1. Right click your eclipse folder, choose Properties-Security-Advanced
2. Click Owner, Edit
3. Check if Current owner is user you are running eclipse with.
4. (If not, check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects", click your user, and click OK to apply.)